# How to Sort Values in Multiple ArrayLists?

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an Arraylist letters which contains letter `f` `r` `t` `d`, and also `two` more Arraylists one of which stores the `row poistion` of a letter and the other stores the `col position` for a letter. 
But after sorting the Arraylist  letters alphabetically (`Collections.sort(letters)`) how can I also sort the row and col values for each letter correspondingly? For example, if the letter `d` has `row = 4`and `col ==3` then after sorting `d` would be in the first place and takes the `row` and ``col values of `f`. How can I do that if letters get their `row` and `col` values.

Given:

```
ArrayList<Character> letters;
ArrayList<Integer> rows;
ArrayList<Integer> cols;
```

Snippet:

```
Collections.sort(letters);
for(int i = 0; i < letters.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.println(letters.get(i).getChar() + rows.get(i) + col.get(i)
}
```

Comment: Do you have to use a List? Looks like Map will be a better option. Since you are Mapping the letter to the rows and columns.

Comment: Perhaps you're using the wrong data structure?

Comment: rgettman's answer has the right idea. It would be best to encapsulate the relationship between letter, row and col in a new class.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is not to sort individual arrays that each store one element of each character.

Create your own class to hold the 3 associated data attributes together, e.g. `Letter`.

Do one of the following:

- Have the class implement `Comparable<Letter>`, adding a `compareTo` method.  Then have an `ArrayList` of `Letter`s on which you can call `Collections.sort`.
- Create another class that implements `Comparator<Letter>` with a `compare` method.  With your `ArrayList` of `Letter`s, call `Collections.sort` passing in an additional parameter that is an instance of your `Comparator`.

Comment: but how could I assign the corresponding rows and cols to letters.

Comment: Your `Letter` class would contain attributes for the row and column as well as the actual character.

Comment: Can I use TreeMap like TreeMap<String, Integer, Intger> ?, @rgettman

Comment: No, `TreeMap` has only 2 type parameters.  But you could have a `TreeMap` whose key is a `Character` and whose value is some pair of `Integers`. It's also possible to maintain a `TreeSet<Letter>`.  That would be best if your list of characters is unique and it changes over time, but it also needs to remain sorted at all times.  But if you only need to sort it once, having an `ArrayList` and a call to `Collections.sort` will work just fine.  Either way, either `Letter` should be `Comparable<Letter>` or you will also create another class that implements `Comparator<Letter>`.

Comment: Thanks for reply, @rgettman, but for `TreeMap` how could I set up pair of `Integers` ? Something line `TreeMap<Character, Integer, Integer> temp` ?

Comment: The simpler, more understandable solution is to create an `ArrayList<Letter>` and sort it as in my answer.

Comment: I do not understand though how to create an `ArrayList<Letter>` and what to do there?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this could not be achieved out-of-box, you can achieve it in two ways:

1. Using any suitable sorting technique (Bubble, Merge, Quick etc), sort them manually. Process all three togather, stop when you get `letters` in desired order.
2. Create a Map, key would be your letter, value will be String (rowNum_colNum, or use any separator between them) and sort that map by keys. Later, break the value and retrieve both the numbers.